# jQuery: get all children whose ID contains part of string

Tags: jquery, html

I have a set of links:

```
<div id="parent">
   <a id="UserFirst" href="#"></a>
   <a id="UserSecond" href="#"></a>
   <a id="UserThird" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

I need a quick way of getting (for example) all the `a` children of `#parent`, whose ID contains the letter `i`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use jquery [`contains selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
$("#parent").find("a[id*='i']").each(function(){
//do something here
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2a3Ck/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. Is it maybe possible to use it the same way, but instead of looking for ID, look for text of the link (`<a href="#">text</a>`)?

Comment: @ojek. Yes It is possible to check text instead of ID, use `$("#parent a:contains('My Text')")`

Answer (score 4):

Use the [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) :

```
$('#parent a[id*="i"]');
```

Answer (score 3):

Use an attribute selector:

```
a[id*="i"]
```

Or `.filter()`:

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    return this.id.indexOf('a') !== -1;
});
```